# Какая разница между System.Security.SecurityException и System.UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, безопасность, исключения

[Конструктор FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo) выбрасывает оба вышеуказанных исключения. Планируется использовать FileInfo для определения корректности пути по аналогии с этим [методом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422111/3129992), так как при использовании [System.IO.File.Exists(string path)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) если у вызывающего оператора нет достаточных полномочий на чтение заданного файла, исключения не создаются, а метод возвращает false вне зависимости от существования path. Мне же необходимо четко определять возникающие ошибки.

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\J.Doe\example.file";
System.IO.FileInfo fi = null;
try {
    fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
} catch (PathTooLongException) {
    // The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length. 
    // For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be less than 248 characters, 
    // and file names must be less than 260 characters.
} catch (NotSupportedException) { 
    // fileName contains a colon (:) in the middle of the string
} catch (SecurityException) {
    // The caller does not have the required permission.
} catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
    // Access to fileName is denied. 
}

if (ReferenceEquals(fi, null)) {
  // file name is not valid
} else {
  // file name is valid
  // Check for existence by calling fi.Exists.
}
```

В чем разница между [System.Security.SecurityException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.securityexception) и [System.UnauthorizedAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception)? При каких обстоятельствах, в данном конкретном случае, возникнет каждое из вышеуказанных исключений?

Comment: Есть [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2339269/5045688) на en.so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исключение `UnauthorizedAccessException` выбрасывается при нарушении уровня доступа на уровне операционной системы. Например при попытке переписать системный файл или при попытке доступа к каталогу без соответствующих прав на чтение. 
[MSDN: Класс UnauthorizedAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Исключение `SecurityException` выбрасывается при нарушении безопасности [CLR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime). Например при использовании технологии ClickOnce попытка создания файлов приведет именно к такой ошибке. 
[MSDN: Класс SecurityException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.securityexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ответ взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339269/3129992).